# Session cookies not saved in browser storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-cookies

I know, there are many of these posts.. But, after applying the settings I know to use as well as what others suggested, nothing seems to make a difference.

I have a client SPA served from an Apache server, and an API on a Node server with the Apache server also serving as a reverse proxy to it. These are in two Docker containers.

The client is served over HTTPS, and I can also reach the API over HTTPS. Upon a "login" route, I receive a Koa.js session cookie from the server. However, the cookies are not being saved to the browser's cookie storage, and therefore not being sent in subsequent requests.

The weird part is I finally got it to work on localhost, but not production.

Apache Config

```
# ... (load modules)

ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
ServerName ${WEB_URI}

DirectoryIndex index.html

RequestHeader unset Proxy early

<Directory / >
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
  AllowOverride none
  Require all granted
  FallbackResource /
</Directory>

Listen 80

# Force HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location '/'>
    Redirect permanent https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!SSLv3:!kRSA

SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLProxyProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"

SSLCertificateFile ${TLS_CERT}
SSLCertificateKeyFile ${TLS_KEY}

Listen 443

# Front end
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>

# Back end
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ${API_URI}
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on

  # These had no apparent effect
  #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
  #ProxyPreserveHost on

  # Turns off checks, whether deemed unecessary (if
  # service is also secured) or in development and
  # localhost would fail the checks
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  # Docker-compose will resolve the container address
  # by name
  ProxyPass / https://api:4430/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://api:4430/
</VirtualHost>
```

Node Config

```js
const server = new (require('koa'))();
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const session = require('koa-session');
const config = require('./config.js');
const { router } = require('./router.js');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

server.keys = [config.SESSION_SECRET];

server
  .use(cors({ credentials: true }))
  .use(
    session(
      {
        // Must have `sameSite: 'none'` and `secure: true` while
        // using CORS
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        domain:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? process.env.WEB_URI
            : 'localhost',
      },
      server
    )
  )
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());

https
  .createServer(
    {
      cert: fs.readFileSync(config.TLS_CERT),
      key: fs.readFileSync(config.TLS_KEY),
    },
    server.callback()
  )
  .listen(config.PORT, config.HOST);
```

#### Client

For every request on the client I'm using these Fetch options:

```js
mode: 'cors',
credentials: 'include'
```

#### Development Config

The only difference in development is I'm ignoring the client in the apache container and using Vite to spin it up outside of Docker on a different localhost port.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import devSSL from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), devSSL()],
  server: {
    https: true,
    // * If API server not UP, this will give an error
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:4000',
        secure: false,
        // changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

#### Response Headers From Post Request

I've replaced the domain with `example` in the headers below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2022 21:47:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1q
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 38
Set-Cookie: koa.sess=eyJhY2NvdW50SWQiOjEsImFjY291bnROYW1lIjoiU2hlbGJ5IiwiX2V4cGlyZSI6MTY2MTIwNDg3MzM5NiwiX21heEFnZSI6ODY0MDAwMDB9; path=/; domain=example.com; samesite=none; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: koa.sess.sig=qQi26orm7Aui0Ga54MBAiGwiYgU; path=/; domain=example.com; samesite=none; secure; httponly
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: can you inspect the response on the proxy server on production and check if the `Set-Cookie`-Header is present & forwarded to the client, and that the `domain` value is valid?

Comment: I don't know how to inspect it on the proxy, but in the browser's network tab, the response has the `Set-Cookie` header. It's just not being saved in the browser's cookie storage.

Comment: please include the `set-cookie` value inside your post or in the comment

Comment: I've appended the post request's response headers to the post

Comment: if possible, could you try to to set `samesite=lax` , and remove `secure`and `httponly` ? also, is your site running on a subdomain?

Comment: also, I am not seeing any `expires` value, please try setting that as well.

Comment: I just tried with `samesite=lax` and an `expires` time of 1 day, and removed `secure` and `httponly`. No luck. The main site is not a subdomain. It's like this - the site is example.com, API is api.example.com.

Comment: so if the `set-cookie` header is returned, I can only imagine that the combination of the cookie options is the issue and you have to try out some combinations. can you post the URL where this is happening?

Comment: Sure, it's currently up at https://unomitted.com/. Keep in mind it's a work-in-progress, especially since the cookie trouble..

Comment: What's strange is that it works on localhost, and it also works on another project at work having the same settings, config, and architecture (API on a subdomain -> Apache reverse proxy & web server -> client on main domain).

Comment: can you try `HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict` + Expires with a high value?

Comment: It's still not saving, even responding with this header  `Set-Cookie: koa.sess=eyJhY2NvdW50SWQiOjEsImFjY291bnROYW1lIjoiU2hlbGJ5IiwiX2V4cGlyZSI6MTY2NDExODUwMzUxMSwiX21heEFnZSI6MjU5MjAwMDAwMH0=; path=/; expires=Sun, 25 Sep 2022 15:08:23 GMT; samesite=strict; secure; httponly`

Comment: I assume that you have set the `domain` value as well and just forgot to add it in your comment?

Comment: Actually, I took it out because I read somewhere that it shouldn't be used in a certain case that I now forgot.. but, I tried with and without `domain`

Comment: I feel like I've wasted your time... it turns out I had a typo on the client side that was preventing the `credentials` property from being set.

Comment: No worries, glad that you figured it out :) happens to me as well